# Upload image with javascript with safari browser not allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

i write javascript code to upload image when click on plus icon the image is uploaded in all browser but in safari browser only i can open file browser but image can't be uploaded and there is very strong thing the plus icon has under it question mark this mark not appear in all other browser .image of safari

[image]

this is html code

```
                    <i class="fa fa-plus" onclick="chooseFile();"> </i>
                    <img id="own-img" src="#" alt="" style="display:block" />
                    <div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden">
                        <input type='file' id="fileInputp" onchange="readURL(this);" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

javascript code

```
 $(".fa-plus").click(function() {
    $("#fileInputp").click();

});

function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#own-img')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(200)
                .height(150);



            $(".fa-plus").css("font-size", "24px");
            $(".add-img").css("display", "inline-block");
            $(".upload-img").css("text-align", "left");


        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
};
```

Comment: Try to set `cursor:pointer` for the `.fa.fa-plus` icon and see if that helps

Comment: What version of safari?